# Erase a certain part of line in GDI+

Tags: c++, windows, gdi+

I have a line similar to an arrow.I draw a text on top of that line.Now I want to erase the part of line that is overlapping the text

My current code is this:

```
SolidBrush *brush1=new SolidBrush(Color::Color(0,167,255));
StringFormat format; 
format.SetAlignment(StringAlignmentCenter); 
format.SetLineAlignment(StringAlignmentCenter); 
graph->DrawLine(myPen,point2,point1); 
graph->DrawString(strdata,wcslen(strdata),&font,point2,&format,brush1);
```

I have also tried

```
AdjustableArrowCap *cap1 = new AdjustableArrowCap(5, 5, true);
Pen *myPen1 = new Pen(Color::Color(0,255,255), width);

myPen->SetCustomEndCap(cap1);
GraphicsPath path;
path.AddLine(point1,point2);
Font font(&FontFamily(L"arial"), 21);
Brush *brush=new SolidBrush(Color::Color(0,255,255,255));

SolidBrush solidBrush(Color(255, 255, 0, 0));

StringFormat format;
format.SetAlignment(StringAlignmentCenter);
format.SetLineAlignment(StringAlignmentCenter);
RectF rectbo;
graph->MeasureString(strdata,wcslen(strdata),&font,PointF::PointF(point2),&rectbo);


graph->DrawLine(myPen,point2,point1);
Region pathRegion(&path);
sta=pathRegion.Intersect(rectbo);
graph->fillRegion(pathRegion,&brush);
graph->DrawString(strdata,wcslen(strdata),&font,point2,&format,brush1);
```

Comment: draw line first and then draw text also make sure brush solid style is enabled so the text overwrite the space below text if you need it

Comment: Can you give a visual example of your current rendering and the desired one? What code do you have so far?

Comment: @Spektre  How do i enable sold brush style.Simply by creating a solid brush?

Comment: @Spektre I want to hide the part of arrow that is bounded by rectangle containing the rectangle.no the part of line bounded by text

Comment: I code in VCL so for me it is just `some_VCL_Obj_or_Form->Canvas->Brush->Style=bsSolid;` in winapi/MFC hard to say but it should be similar.

Comment: You can still before drawing the text draw some rectangle to clear the wanted space.

Comment: So if I use solid brush it hides the part of line bounded by string..Not by rectangle which bounds the string.

Comment: @user3845376: Please put relevant information in the question's body, not in the comment's section. I've added the code from your comment to the question body and marked your comment as obsolete; next time, please edit the question straight away if you have more relevant information to add to the question. Thanks!

Comment: @spektre yes if draw a rectangle its visible.if i make it transparent the back line is also visible.I donot want to display the bounded rectangle.

Comment: bsSolid overwrites the whole rectangle (from your question text is this what you want) bsClear leave paper pixels be (no filling this is what you want from last comment) so which one it is?

Comment: &statx i am very new to stackoverlow So i donot know the Norms here.Next time i take care of it

Comment: @user3845376: Thanks! If you want to actively learn about how Stack Overflow works, take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), or [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) (where policy and norms are actively discussed and developed).

Comment: I want bSSolid.But we donot have something similar in gdi+

Comment: @stakx yes i will look into it

Comment: search it in hatch patterns (it may be is just calling slight differently) it is just an enum just like bsClear ... also it could be found in windows.h perhaps

Comment: added answer. and removed VCL tag from your question (you are not using VCL that is Borland/Embarcadero specific library on top of WinAPI/MFC)

Answer (score 1):

draw line first and then draw text

- also make sure brush solid/clear style is enabled
- so the text overwrite the space below text
- and paper is cleared/or leaved as is

I found it for you

- [Brush Winapi refference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145035(v=vs.85).aspx)
- so set `LOGBRUSH::lbStyle=BS_NULL;` for bsClear equivalent
- and `LOGBRUSH::lbStyle=BS_SOLID;` for bsSolid equivalent

Comment: GDI doesnot allow to draw woth LOGBRUSH

Comment: @user3845376 try to use NULL pointer instead of brush or look into GDI+ docs for brush style property. If your problem is not solved then do not check the answer ... until it is solved ...

Comment: If I write NULL it removes the string.

Comment: GDI supported LOGBRUSH but gdi+ doesnot support log brushes.It doesnot allow you to set propoert there are fixed brushes like solid brush hatch brush and pattern brush

Comment: @user3845376 what about hatching bitmap with empty filling pattern ? if GDI+ allows to set custom hatch map then use it with empty bitmap. also a possibility would be to to create solid brush and change it property in that brush structure directly (but you would need access permitions to it for that) but I still think that there should be something like ClearBrush or NullBrush in GDI+ it is very often used thing in GDI so it would be silly not to implement it to GDI+ ...

Comment: @user3845376 try look also for HollowBrush (it seem that BS_NULL/BS_CLEAR is also called VS_HOLLOW in WinAPI)